# cabal haddock failing because function is defined in multiple files

Tags: haskell, haddock

I try to generate documentation for my executable using `cabal haddock`. My project structure looks like this:

```
~/.../project_name
project_name.cabal
Setup.hs
src/
    Main.hs
    Data/
    ...
 test/
    MainTestSuite
    ...
```

When I run `cabal haddock --executable` it fails with the following error message:

```
module ‘projects-0.1.0.0:Main’ is defined in multiple files: dist/build/tmp-8215/src/Main.hs
                                                             dist/build/tmp-8215/./Setup.hs
```

The `Source.hs` file has these contents:

```
import Distribution.Simple
main = defaultMain
```

The `ghc` Version is `7.8.3` and the haddock version is `2.14.3`.

Comment: Probably an instance of https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/284 , follow the links to issues in GHC/cabal in there.